# I'm make a program of a random string from a List and I ran to a problem. It ask the user to press p for previous string from the list

Tags: python, list, loops, random

Each press of the letter "p" should move backward through the list display the previous element. If the zeroth element is current being displayed, wrap around and display the last element.

```
import random

myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
inList = print(random.choice(my_List))
while True:
    userQuest = input("Press 'p' for previous or 'n' for next ")
        if userQuest.lower == 'p':
            pre_num = my_list[my_list.index(inList) -1]

        else:
            print(done)
```

Comment: *I ran to a problem* well, what is the problem?

Comment: I get the random letter from the list and when I press p to get the previous letter from the list I just get an error.

Comment: Are we suppose to guess what is the error?

Comment: Yeah I try to figure it out where the error.

Comment: You have the stacktrace for that. Any way, the current code won't even reach the `input` as you are using `my_List` and `my_list` while the variable name is `myList`. Please provide [minimal and reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `userQuest.lower` should be `userQuest.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in the code.
Besides, `inList = print(random.choice(my_List))` will always return a `NoneType` to `inList`, which you can check via `type(inList)`. You should change it to `inList = random.choice(my_List)`.

The code below should work for your case.

**Please note there will be an edge case**: if the random choice returns `'A'`, the `pre_num` will be `'F'`. Please be sure that's the result you are expecting.

```py
import random

myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
inList = random.choice(myList)
print(f'inList: {inList}')

while True:
    userQuest = input("Press 'p' for previous or 'n' for next ")
    if userQuest.lower() == 'p':
        pre_num = myList[myList.index(inList) - 1]
        print(pre_num)
    else:
        print('done')
```

Comment: Your code always prints the same element because `inList` is not updated.

Comment: @ack That's right. My solution only fixed the errors, not the logic. I agree with you that the inList should be updated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
inList = random.choice(myList)

# remember position of element
pos_inList = myList.index(inList)

while True:
    print(f'inList: {myList[pos_inList]}')
    userQuest = input("Press 'p' for previous or 'n' for next ")
    if 'p' in userQuest.lower():
        # decrement position
        # wrap around from 'A' to 'F' using modulo function
        pos_inList = (pos_inList - 1) % len(myList)
    else:
        print('done')
        break
```